# Add cacert certificates to kopete

Tags: kde, certificates, kopete

ca-cert was recently removed from the ca-certificates bundle, and I would like to readd it, at least to kopete so I don't get the invalid certificate warnings because one of the jabber servers I connect to has a ca-cert signed certificate.